# Creating a one-to-many relationship in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content-type `Team Members`. Each Team Member has a `Position`. Each `Position` has a `Category`.

E.g.:

Category 1

- Position 1
- Position 2

Category 2

- Position 3
- Position 4

If you create a new peace of content using the content-type `Team Member` you should be able to choose one and only one `Position`.

I then want to render all the Team Members in the order of the above example. So First you'll see the title of the first Category, then the title of the fist Position, then all team members with that position etc.

Can anyone tell me what's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to:

- create a multilevel taxonomy
- add a term reference field to your Team Members content type (you can try 
  [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module if you have long/complex hierarchy)
- use views ( possibly a combination of [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) and [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) ) to display it the way you want

Comment: hey, thanks. I now did it by creating a taxonomy vocabulary for categories and positions and just added a term reference field to each position term. Displaying is done in an module since I think it's way! easier to grasp whats going on when there's code instead of 200 configs in a view. :)

Comment: that should work too. yeah, configuring ans then styling views can be cumbersome))